# Transform text between delimiters sed regex

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I want to transform Cyrillic characters with Latin ones, **only** in-between specific delimiters - `$$` and `[]`. I'm having problems specifying the range for the transformation.

I came up with:

```
sed -i '' '/[\[$][^$\[]*[\[$]/ y/АаІіВСсЕеРТтОоКкХхМ/AaIiBCcEePTtOoKkXxM/' wrong.txt
```

but this replacing all text in the following example:

*wrong.txt:*

```
Тут тeкст $DЕV$ ще текст...,.. $РRОVS$
 $NUМ|Y$ $DUСАТS|Y$¤ багато тексту" 
"$АDJ$ dhfg [Rооt.GеtNаmе]%
 $NАМЕ$ \n"
§Y$VАL$§!¤"
```

Note: I use OS X.

Note2: The transformation is not the problem, the regex is.

Expected output (i.e. text inside the specified tags becomes latinized):

```
Тут текст $DEV$ ще текст...,.. $PROVS$
 $NUM|Y$ $DUCATS|Y$¤ багато тексту" 
"$ADJ$ dhfg [Root.GetName]%
 $NAME$ \n"
§Y$VAL$§!¤"
[GetCapitalName]
```

Comment: It looks like what's delimited are Latin characters, not Cyrillic ones. Also, is that transformation correct? My Russian is super rusty, but `С` should become `S`, and `Р` becomes `R`, no?

Comment: What's the desired output? The root problem is that `y` acts on the whole line if it matches. The address only determines that, and doesn't select which part of the line to act on.

Comment: @BenjaminW. if you want to specify cyrillic letters, this ones are Ukrainian.

Comment: Also they may look visually the same, you can check, they're actually not. https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: "The root problem is that y acts on the whole line if it matches." - that's a bummer. I thought I can specify a range for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134634/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-al-crow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with sed is (as so often) a bit of a pain, and a Perl or awk solution could be much shorter and better readable – but here's one in sed.

It is called with

```
sed -E -f sedscr.sed wrong.txt
```

where `wrong.txt` is your input, and the sed script is in `sedscr.sed` and looks as follows:

```
/\$[^$]*\$/ {
    :label1
    h
    s/.*(\$[^$]*\$).*/\1/
    y/АаІіВСсЕеРТтОоКкХхМ/AaIiBCcEePTtOoKkXxM/
    s/\$/~~/g
    G
    s/(.*)\n(.*)\$[^$]*\$(.*)/\2\1\3/
    /\$[^$]*\$/b label1
    s/~~/$/g
}
/\[[^]]*\]/ {
    :label2
    h
    s/.*(\[[^]]*\]).*/\1/
    y/АаІіВСсЕеРТтОоКкХхМ/AaIiBCcEePTtOoKkXxM/
    s/[][]/~~/g
    G
    s/(.*)\n(.*)\[[^]]*\](.*)/\2\1\3/
    /\[[^]]*\]/b label2
    :label3
    s/~~/[/
    s/~~/]/
    /~~/b label3
}
```

The two main blocks each check if the line contains a `$$` or a `[]` pair, and if yes, they go about translating it. The pattern is always the same: assume your line looks like

```
abcdef $abc$ abcdef $def$ abc
```

and you want to transliterate to uppercase. First, we copy the pattern space to the hold space (`h`), then remove everything outside of the last pair of markers (`s/.*(\$[^$]*\$).*/\1/`). Now we transliterate with `y/abcdef/ABCDEF/`.

To mark the pair a done, we replace it by something not in the text: two `~` characters (`s/\$/~~/g`). `G` appends the hold space to the pattern space, which now looks like

```
~~DEF~~
abcdef $abc$ abcdef $def$ abc
```

The complicated substitution `s/(.*)\n(.*)\$[^$]*\$(.*)/\2\1\3/` results in

```
abcdef $abc$ abcdef ~~DEF~~ abc
```

Now we check if there still is a pair of `$`, and if yes, we branch to `:label1` (`/\$[^$]*\$/b label1`). When we're not branching any longer, all the `$$` have been processed, and we can replace the `~~` with `$` again (`s/~~/$/g`).

The `[]` in the second block are in principle the same; the only difference is when replacing the `~~`, we use another loop because we have to insert alternating `[` and `]`.

This is the output:

```
$ sed -E -f sedscr.sed wrong.txt
Тут тeкст $DEV$ ще текст...,.. $PROVS$
 $NUM|Y$ $DUCATS|Y$¤ багато тексту"
"$ADJ$ dhfg [Root.GetName]%
 $NAME$ \n"
§Y$VAL$§!¤"
```

Or, more illustrative, before and after in my terminal emulator with non-latin characters visible:

[image: terminal printscreen]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how do I suppress printing of the output?
I tried adding `-n` after `-E` but it brakes the command execution.

Comment: @AlCrow For in-place replacement? `sed -i '' -E -f sedscr.sed wrong.txt` should work.